# Passing Data between ViewController without using Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I know the question is repeated, but requirement is little different so posting here. I know how to pass value from one ViewController to other by defining property to hold the value passed from first ViewController. I am attaching the `ScreenShot` for better understanding. [image] What I did is embed a `UIPageViewController`into `NavigationController(SwipeBetweenViewController)`. From `UIPageViewController` calling `UIViewController(ProfileViewController)` programmatically. After clicking `LOG IN` button, getting some response, storing it in a variable. Now what I have to do is pass that variable to `ProfileViewController`.I have defined a `property` in ProfileViewController.h, `imported` ProfileViewController.h into LoginViewController.m. I am passing data directly between `LoginViewController` to `ProfileViewController`, should it be passed from `UiPageViewController`. Here is the code, I have tried but its not working. Execution control remains on the same page, no navigation.

**ProfileViewController.h**

```
 @interface KKProfileViewController : UIViewController
 @property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *userEmailId;
 @end
```

**LoginViewController.m**

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        // Handle error
    }
    else {
        NSError *tempError;

        NSDictionary* response=(NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&tempError];
        NSString *loginResponse =response[@"message"];
        _emailId =response[@"email"];

        if ([loginResponse isEqualToString:@"Welcome"])

        {
            [self passLoginDataForward];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSuccess" sender:self];

        }
        else
        {
            //code for error alert

        }

        NSLog(@"Response is :%@", response);

    }

}


-(void)passLoginDataForward
{

    ProfileViewController *viewControllerProfile =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileViewController"];

    viewControllerProfile.userEmailId = _emailId;
    NSLog(@"user Email %@", viewControllerProfile.userEmailId);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerProfile animated:YES];
}
```

**SwipeViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
firstVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileViewController"];
secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashboardViewController"];
thirdVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newsViewController"];
viewControllerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
viewControllerArray = @[firstVC,secondVC,thirdVC];
self.currentPageIndex = 0;
self.isPageScrollingFlag = NO;
self.hasAppearedFlag = NO;
}
-(void)setupPageViewController 
{
pageController = (UIPageViewController*)self.topViewController;
pageController.delegate = self;
pageController.dataSource = self;
[pageController setViewControllers:@[[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:0]]    direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
 [self syncScrollView];
  }
```

Comment: Try after declaring Property Strong.

Comment: what's the NSLog result while printing viewControllerProfile.userEmailId? Does it print the value properly ?

Comment: Your profile view controller isn't actually connected to anything in your storyboard, so while you can instantiate it the way you are, it doesn't follow the flow of your storyboard.  From your login view controller do you want to move to your page view controller?  And that should have the profile view controller as its first page?

Comment: @ronak: Nothing happened...checked.

Comment: @Vivek: yes, it is printing the desired value, issue is in navigating the data.

Comment: Yes @Paulw11, I have to go to PageViewController cause, I have implemented swipe-view. Can u explain, how can I pass the data. Should i have to post that code for PageViewController swipe implementation.

Comment: If the page controller is the next view controller you are presenting, then yes that is the view controller you need to instantiate and pass the data to and present

Comment: as a alternative, you can declare one string in your .pch and store value in it and use that value in next viewcontroller.

Comment: @KunalKumar use NSUserDefaults and store value inside of it or you can define globle valribale too.

Comment: First question, is your login view controller embedded in navigation controller? Second Question, do you want to push the pageviewcontroller or profile viewcontroller?

Comment: Have you checked the value of userEmailId in ViewDidLoad of ProfileViewController ? What it prints there ?

Comment: @Johnykutty: 1)No, I am using segue from loginViewController to NavigationController. 2) I want to push PageViewController, cause there is an array containing that ProfileViewController and some other ViewControllers.

Comment: @paulw: means I have to pass data first to page controller and after that to ProfileViewController.

Comment: which segue you are using push, present etc??. The problem is because your login view controller doesn't have a navigation controller and you are trying to push view controller. Nothing will hapen

Comment: @Johnykutty: Now getting it, I was using it first, but deleted coz i was getting navigated but wasn't getting the data. Give me a minute, let me check again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because your login view controller may not have a navigation controller and you are trying to push view controller. Nothing will happen in this case.

If you want to push the page view controller to login views navigation stack, embed your login view controller in a navigation controller(Select login view controller **Editor>Ember>Navigation controller**) And add a segue to pageviewcontroller(directly from login view controller, not from any button). Add an identifier for the segue(say `yourSegueID`) Then implement the following method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueID"]) {
        UIPageViewController *pageViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        ProfileViewController *viewControllerProfile =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileViewController"];

        viewControllerProfile.userEmailId = _emailId;

        [pageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewControllerProfile] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Then call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueID" sender:nil];
```

**Second option**

If you want to create new navigation stack, as in your current storyboard implementation, make the segue from login view controller to navigation controller a present modal segue then change following line in `prepareForSegue`

```
    UIPageViewController *pageViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

to

```
UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];
UIPageViewController *pageViewController = navController.viewControllers[0];
```

**Update**

Updating as per your new code for swipeviewcontroller
In this case, You have to add email property in swipe view controller too. Then set it in prepare for segue method. Then set profile view controllers property in the swipe view controller viewdidload

Comment: Please check edited code and suggest wat to do. Going to embed login viewcontroller into navigation controller.

Comment: able to get the data by second option coz i have to implement swipe view, but now the problem is profileviewcontroller getting executed two times, at first we get the data, after that nil. Please consider my edited code.

Comment: That code getting complicated. Second time getting nil because, you are creating it again in the Swipeviewcontroller. Will update the answer

Comment: exactly, second time control only come to the swipeviewcontroller and lost the reference for viewControllerProfile.userEmailId. Take your time Johnykutty.

Comment: ll try n let u know, please be with this post for sometime.

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
         {
             if (error) 
            {
                // Handle error
            }
            else 
            {
                NSError *tempError;

                NSDictionary* response=(NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&tempError];
                NSString *loginResponse =response[@"message"];
                _emailId =response[@"email"];

            ///////////////////////
            //set your Email in nsuserdefaults

            [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults][setObject:_emailId forKey:@"email"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

            ///////////////////////


                if ([loginResponse isEqualToString:@"Welcome"])

               {
                   [self passLoginDataForward];

               }
                else
               {
                 //code for error alert

               }

                NSLog(@"Response is :%@", response);

            }

 }


-(void)passLoginDataForward
{

ProfileViewController *viewControllerProfile =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerProfile animated:YES];
}
```

Get Value in ProfileViewController.m

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        userEmailId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"email"];

 }
```

Comment: Don't want to use NSUserDefaults, this is not the right way to pass data between viewcontrollers. NSUserDefaults should be used to store apps specific data like app-setting etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
YourViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
vc.something = something;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Use this instead of `self.storyboard`.